# What does ℝ$x$ stand for?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The question says suppose that $A$ is a $5\times4$ matrix and null($A$)=$ℝx$ for some column $x\ne0$. Can dim(im$A$)=2? First, I am not sure what $ℝx$ looks like and second, is the question equivalent to asking if dim(null$A$)=2 as the max rank is 4?

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \mathbf{x} = \{ r \mathbf{x} : r \in \mathbb{R} \}$, so it's the one-dimensional space including $\mathbf{x}$. Equivalently, it's the set of all vectors colinear with $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R} x = \{\lambda x \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$. And if $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, then you have $\dim(\ker(A)) + \dim(\text{Im}(A)) = n.$

Comment: @Esperluet Is it regardless of the rank, like if m>n?

Comment: @CoolKid It is always valid, even if $m > n$.

Answer (score 1):

To the first question $\mathbb R x$ is usually just a notation defined as follows:

$$\mathbb R x := \{ tx | t \in \mathbb R \}$$ I hope this makes more sense now!

Comment: Um, would you mind telling me more detail? I am not sure why the answer says m=dim(row A)=rank A=dim(col A)=n. Thanks